# My GridView will not populate with data from my SQL datasource

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I have created a GridView that is bound to a local SQL database file (mdf).  The database connection is successful.  I do receive the error message from my EmptyDataText="No Data" on the webpage where the GridView is suppose to be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my div holding the GridView:

```
   <div style="border: 10px hidden #0B4A80; height: 108px; width: 494px; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 40px;" >
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" 
      ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' 
      SelectCommand="SELECT AspNetUsers.EmailConfirmed, AspNetUser.UserName, AspNetUsers.FirstName, AspNetUsers.LastName, AspNetUsers.BusinessName, AspNetRoles.Name FROM AspNetUsers INNER JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetRoles.Id INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId AND AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" SelectMethod ="" UpdateMethod ="" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyNames="Id" EmptyDataText="No Data" EnableModelValidation="false" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="10px" Height="75px" PageSize="3" Width="472px">
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="User Information" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="EmailConfirmed" HeaderText="EmailConfirmed" SortExpression="EmailConfirmed"></asp:DynamicField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="BusinessName" HeaderText="Business Name" SortExpression="BusinessName"></asp:DynamicField>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="UserName"></asp:DynamicField>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Role"  SortExpression="Role" ></asp:DynamicField>
       </Columns>
      <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#D7E4FF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#1484AA" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />          
    </asp:GridView>
  </div>
```

Here is my Code behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      BindGrid1();
      BindGrid2();
    }

      private void BindGrid2()
      {
        String queryString = "SELECT [EmailConfirmed], [UserName], [FirstName], [LastName], [BusinessName], [Name] FROM AspNetUsers INNER JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetRoles.Id INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId AND AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId";
        DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
          GridView2.DataSource = ds;
          GridView2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
          Response.Write("Unable to conenct to the database");
        }

      }

      DataSet GetData(String queryString)
      {
        //Retrive the connection string in the web.config file.
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
          // Connect to the database and run query.
          SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
          SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

          //Fill the dataSet.
          adapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
          // The connection failed. Display an error message.
          Response.Write("Unable to connect to the database.");
          Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        return ds;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove your code-behind database calls. You are already populating the gridview from the ASPX page's SQL data source.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
      <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="EmailConfirmed" HeaderText="EmailConfirmed" SortExpression="EmailConfirmed" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="PasswordHash" HeaderText="PasswordHash" SortExpression="PasswordHash" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="SecurityStamp" HeaderText="SecurityStamp" SortExpression="SecurityStamp" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneNumber" HeaderText="PhoneNumber" SortExpression="PhoneNumber" />
      <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="PhoneNumberConfirmed" HeaderText="PhoneNumberConfirmed" SortExpression="PhoneNumberConfirmed" />
      <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="TwoFactorEnabled" HeaderText="TwoFactorEnabled" SortExpression="TwoFactorEnabled" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="LockoutEndDateUtc" HeaderText="LockoutEndDateUtc" SortExpression="LockoutEndDateUtc" />
      <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="LockoutEnabled" HeaderText="LockoutEnabled" SortExpression="LockoutEnabled" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="AccessFailedCount" HeaderText="AccessFailedCount" SortExpression="AccessFailedCount" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="TrialExpiration" HeaderText="TrialExpiration" SortExpression="TrialExpiration" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" 
ConnectionString='......' SelectCommand="SELECT AspNetUsers.EmailConfirmed, AspNetUser.UserName, AspNetUsers.FirstName, AspNetUsers.LastName, AspNetUsers.BusinessName, AspNetRoles.Name FROM AspNetUsers LEFT OUTER JOIN AspNetUserRoles ON AspNetUsers.Id = AspNetUserRoles.UserId LEFT OUTER JOIN AspNetRoles ON AspNetRoles.Id = AspNetUserRoles.RoleId"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**C# code-behind:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Identity.  I am still receiving the "No Data" error message.  The original Select statement was create when I used "Create Data Source wizard.  I just ran this again with you Select Statement.   When I select "Text Query" only the Column headers are returned.  I have one registered user in the AspNetUser Table.

Comment: @joey.coyle I don't understand what you mean. Does the SQL return any records when executed against the database ?

Comment: @joey.coyle do you have any records in the `AspNetRoles` or `AspNetUserRoles` tables ?

Comment: if I do a "Show Table Data" on the AspNetUser table in my project, one record is returned.  I just cannot get this record to show in my GridView.  If I edit the select statement in my project by going to Design view and selecting "Configure Data Source" on my datasource object.  There is an option to test the query statement.  When I do this only the column headers are returned.  I am assuming I should see my one record.

Comment: @joey.coyle I have updated my SQL statement, can you please try that and let me know.

Comment: OK, we are making progress.  I am now able to see my record when I test the query string but my GridView still shows no data error message.  Can you look at my BindGrid2() method connection string and see if that is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to open the connection?

```
 using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
 {
      connection.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

      //Fill the dataSet.
      adapter.Fill(ds);
 }
```

Comment: I added you code here with no affect.  I still get no Data.  I do not think the connection to the data source is the problem.